# Running Total of object property with previous element with matching property : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have array of object like below.

```
var arr = [{Month: "Nov-2020",Track: "MS",total: 100},
{Track: "ZZ", Month: "Nov-2020", total: 80},  
{Track: "ZZ", Month: "Dec-2020", total: 20}, 
{Track: "MS", Month: "Dec-2020", total: 20}]
```

Now I want this is like below

```
var arrNew = [{Month: "Nov-2020",Track: "MS",total: 100},
{Track: "ZZ", Month: "Nov-2020", total: 80},  
{Track: "ZZ", Month: "Dec-2020", total: 100}, 
{Track: "MS", Month: "Dec-2020", total: 120}]
```

I have tried to use reduce and map but couldnot able to figure it our. Can someone guild me here. Here I am matching element based on Track and adding the previous total value to current object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it work but not sure if that is perfect solution or there might be another good solution available. Looking for suggestion.

```
var arr = [{Month: "Nov-2020",Track: "MS",total: 100},
 {Track: "ZZ", Month: "Nov-2020",  total: 80},
 {Track: "ZZ", Month: "Dec-2020",  total: 20},
 {Track: "AA", Month: "Nov-2020",  total: 30},
 {Track: "AA", Month: "Dec-2020",  total: 20},
 {Track: "MS", Month: "Dec-2020",  total: 20}]

const result = arr.reduce((r, value, i) => {
const {Month, Track, total} = value

if(i > 0){
    var found = r.find(x=> x.Track == value.Track)
  if(found){
    const cumVal = found.total
    const newDatum = { total: total + cumVal, Month,  Track}
    r.push(newDatum);
  }else{
    const newDatum = { total: total, Month,  Track}
    r.push(newDatum);
  }
}else{
  const newDatum = { total: total, Month,  Track}
  r.push(newDatum);
}
return r;
}, [])
console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrNew = arr.map(element => element.Month === "Dec-2020"? Object.assign(element, {total: 100}): element);
```

Comment: Thank You Lin, Month will be dynamic, so not sure hardcoding is an good idea, also there was an issue with the output in my question. Just updated my question